# how to check if a link was clicked?

Tags: jquery, function, click, contains

Here is my problem. I am editing a website that is generating all the content of the website in a loop from the server side to the ***PHP*** and then I am asked to manipulate the website using [***jQuery***](http://jquery.com).

The question here is that, a lot of link tags that exists on the website have no `ID`s associcated with them. So I am asked to solve a problem, where if one of the link tags is clicked, some **jQuery** logic takes place.

In my case, if link tag with text **"See All"** is clicked. I am supposed to carry out some code execution but how exactly do I write it?

Is it as simple as writing:

```
$("a:contains('See All')").click(function() {
  // do something
});
```

because that doesn't seem to be working. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Exact matching for `See All` and so on**

```
$("a")
     .filter(function() {   // apply filter() to for exact text matching
          return $(this).text() == 'See All';
     }).click(function(e) {
          // To prevent page reload you need .preventDefault()
          e.preventDefault();
          alert('hello');
     });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/e4wCa/)**

**Check containment of `See All` (not exact match)**

```
$("a").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().match('See All'); // a little change here
}).click(function() {
    alert('hello');
});
```

or  just use `:contains()`

```
$('a:contains(See All)').on('click', function() {
   alert('Hello');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/pLEsD/1/)**

**Some extra note**

If your links generate after DOM ready then you need to try with ".on" event binding like:

```
$('#container').on('click', 'a:contains(See All)', function() {
  alert('Hello');
});
```

and in case the client was using jQuery v-1.7, then try ".delegate" event as follows:

```
$('#container').delegate('a:contains(See All)', 'click', function() {
  alert('Hello');
});
```

Comment: Okay, I will check this solution out tomorrow and see if it works. Much appreciated bud. Just a question, using filter won't add much overhead would it?

Comment: @user1429805 no overhead, and it is working just fine check my working sample

Comment: Thanks dude, it works like a charm. I might use "text.match()" since they are using jquery 1.6.x and not jquery 1.7 which supports "on" event now. I guess i could try "delegate' in its place, i'll try.

Comment: @TylerDurden83 Welcome, buddy, If your links generate after DOM ready that means after page load then you should try `delegate event`.

Comment: Hey "thecodeparadox", I just tried the delegate code and it works like a charm buddy. Thanks a lot. Your help here is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the `'` in `'See All'`?

Also, to make sure that it doesn't redirect the users to the link in `href`, use `e.preventDefault()`

```
$("a:contains(See All)").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // do something
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/99LMh/

Comment: I think your checking using `:contains()` will fail, if `a` contains text like `See All 2` and so on.

Comment: I think your recommendation on e.preventDefault() was a great one, i might insert that in there as well. Thanks a lot for the help, inserting your code with "thecodeparadox" should make this thing work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a link shortening service (e.g. Google's https://goo.gl/, or click to tweet's clicktotweet.com, free for 5 and paid there after).  The use the shortened link.

This will keep track of the number of times the link is clicked.

Now what you were looking for, no